# Trying to fill map 100%

Tags: axiom-verge

In the topmost room in Kur, I can't fill in the middle, top two spaces on the map. I have the third trench coat and the extended drone launch. I've tried jumping, teleporting, and throwing the drone from every good spot I can find but it's not enough to reach the spaces. Any tips? Not using cheat codes by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't figured this out: use the grapple on the top portion of the map above the entrance of  E-KUR-MAH. I dismissed it at first because it didn't look like you could grapple the top.